# Curl и изменение размера изображения

Tags: php, curl

Есть ссылка на изображение, которое закачивается на сервер с помощью curl

```
public function download_remote_file_with_curl($file_url, $save_to) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$file_url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $file_content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $downloaded_file = fopen($save_to, 'w');
    fwrite($downloaded_file, $file_content);
    fclose($downloaded_file);

}
```

$file_url - ссылка на картинку, $save_to - директория на моем сервере

Обычные php загрузчики не подходят, т. к. картинок много, и заканчивается оперативка, функция не успевает завершиться.

Но фотки большие, и нужно их уменьшить До загрузки на мой сервер, так вот как это совместить с curl?

Comment: Вы можете использовать Imagemagick для загрузки изображения по адресу, трансформировать его а уже затем сохранить куда надо. Читайте документацию на http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.readimagefile.php

Comment: @DanielProtopopov а оперативку не будет жрать?

Comment: Не знаю, определится только на практике в конкретном примере

Comment: @DanielProtopopov на хостинге не установлен imagemagick