# Загрузка изображений на сервер по ссылке

Tags: php, изображения, загрузка, обработка-изображений

Написал парсинг товаров для интернет магазина, но появилась проблема: Большое кол-во изображений (около 1000) нужно загрузить на сервер (у каждого своя ссылка) при этом уменьшить их вес (т.к. весят по 2-8 МБ) до 200-500 кб. Подскажите, как это сделать, чтобы скрипт не перегружал оперативную память

Comment: Уточните в чем конкретно проблема. Вы уже реализовали загрузку изображений на сервер и хотите ёё оптимизировать ?

Comment: @koks_rs Да, загрузка уже реализована. Использую curl для загрузки изображения в класс (временный файл), затем изменяю его размер, и сохраняю на сервер, но этот метод перегружает оперативную память, и скрипт не успевает доработать, загружаются не все изображения.

Comment: Это ваш сервер?

Comment: @Crantisz нет, хостинг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться онлайн сервисами наподобие [rsz.io](https://rsz.io), [kraken.io](https://kraken.io/docs/image-resizing) и др., которые отдадут вам изменённое изображение; и да, не плодите [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623597/curl-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?noredirect=1) пожалуйста. Последняя альтернатива - бесплатный сервис от Гугла ([описание на английском тут](https://gist.github.com/carlo/5379498))

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо разделить локику. Сначала парсите все изображения как есть. И только при отрисовке каталога урезайте каждую в цикле вывода товаров. 
Ну или как вариант постите изображения товаров от источника.

Comment: Размеры фоток у источника большие, страницы долго подгружаются, а процесс урезки картинки при загрузке каталога не будет тормозить загрузку страницы?

Comment: не думаю. вы же не выводите весь каталог товаров сразу? Скорее всего с пагинацией и товаров 50-100 на страницу. Я работаю с опенкарт, и там локика обработки изо такая: обратились к картинке во время формирования массива товаров, обработали на лету, запушили в подмассив товара. Попутно кешнув, но этим занимается сам "мотор". 
однозначно уверен в одном - парсить и одновременно обрабатывать и выводить есть очень не оно)

Comment: А какой функцией у Вас обрабатывается картинка?

Comment: imagecreatetruecolor

Comment: наверное, надо подробнее: при загрузке картинки на сервер дёргаем imagecreatetruecolor на предмет создания картинки с заданными в конфиге размерами (для тамбсов, фото в каталоге, карты товара и т.п. для всего свои размеры). И сохраняем две: оригинал и копию. И уже при запросе клиентом, например, каталога, при формировании массива товаров, берутся изменённые картинки если таковые созданы ранее, либо на лету создаются миниатюры теми же классами. Это в общем. Конкретнее только на примере классов опенкарта.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте увеличить количество памяти, выделяемое под скрипт:

```
<? ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Так-же, возможно, не хватает времени:

```
<? set_time_limit(500);
```

Однако если это не поможет (например хостинг не даст установить достаточно много), придется копировать изображения пачками, по 10000, по 1000 или по 100